# How many ScheduledExecutorService, each with 1 thread, can JVM handle?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, threadpool, scheduledexecutorservice

I have created a class representing a user session and that user session sends a ping to another service every 25 seconds. For that, I have used `ScheduledExecutorService` and `ScheduledFuture` in that class.

```
public class UserSession {
 
  private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;
  private ScheduledFuture<?> keepAliveTask;
    
  public UserSession() {
      this.scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
      this.keepAliveTask = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {         
            this.sendPing();
      }, 25L, 25L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
  .....
  .....
}
```

Now the issue is, there will be around 4000-5000 user sessions and hence there will be 4000-5000 `UserSession` objects, each with its own `ScheduledExecutorService` with single thread. So if I understand this correctly, there will be around 4000-5000 threads, each one responsible for sending out pings of the respective session.

So, will JVM handle that many no of threads or `ScheduledExecutorService`? I know it depends upon CPU, but is this a good idea? Or is there any better alternative?

Comment: I think, most systems have no problem with even 100,000 threads, but that doesn’t mean that this design was a good idea. The entire purpose of `ScheduledExecutorService` is to be shared, to avoid such a waste of resources. Your ping actions could be easily handled by a single thread…

Comment: Yup, I settled with the same opinion and just created one task in ScheduledExecutorService which sends out pings for each active sessions

Answer (score 1):

JVM delegates the threads to the underlying OS.

So, your question is more a concern if the OS and hardware (mostly, the processor and its cores) can support that many threads in a process.

> is this a good idea? Or is there any better alternative?

I don't know the boundaries of your project. Other ideas to achieve the goals:

- [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) and Message Queue application, for example ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, even Apache Kafka.
- An actor model system like [Akka](https://akka.io) with [actors](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/index-actors.html) and [scheduler](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scheduler.html)

Comment: Quartz I think also uses threads to execute jobs. Not sure how I can use RabbitMQ or Kafka. because my goal is to send ping requests to the service over WebSocket.

Comment: You send a message to a queue and the other component listens for that message to process a request. This is asynchronous communication and will handle the threads behind the scenes. Since you didn't provide much info on the project, I suggested using that kind of communication.